# Saving Spark DataFrame as zip archive

Tags: scala, apache-spark, zip

Currently we are saving DataFrames as gzip archives however one of our data consumers does not support this file format. Is there a way to save Spark Data Frame as zip archive?

```
val dfWriter = sourceDf.repartition(1)
  .write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")

if (archived)
  dfWriter.option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
```

Comment: try `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec` for more info https://gist.github.com/chetan/6524829

Comment: I believe sending a textfile downstream would be better than sending a ZIP. you are anyway using `repartition(1)` and zipping it is not going to save any space.